# Issue on parsing and sum using database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sum

im creating an invoice function. It involves 3 pages.

The first page which is a form that takes in the variable of customer name, description, amount, quantity and discount.

The second page parses all these variable, make a new variable called total that will calculate amount X quantity minus away the discount and then insert into database then redirect to the third page.

The Third Page
Is supposed to sum the total column for a final total variable. How do i use the sum function to calculate the total in order to get the final total? And also how do i store all the variables printed out so that i can store them into database? 
E.g. i want to print out all the descriptions, customer name, amount, quantity and total entered in page one and then add the final total which was calculated in page 3 .

Page one(submit form)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
             <title>Untitled Document</title>

                 <script type="text/javascript">
                  var count = 0;

                    function addTextArea() {
                    count = count + 1;
                    var div = document.getElementById('name');
                    div.innerHTML += "<div> <input type='text' name='name[]' value='' " + "id=name" + count + "> </div>";
                    div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
                    var div = document.getElementById('quantity');
                    div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='quantity[]' value ='' " + "id=quantity" + count + "></div>";
                    div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
                    var div = document.getElementById('amount');
                    div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='amount[]' value ='' " + "id=amount" + count + "></div>";
                    div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
                    var div = document.getElementById('discount');
                    div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='discount[]' value ='' " + "id=discount" + count + "></div>";
                    div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
                                                }

                function removeTextArea() {
                    document.getElementById("name" + count).remove();
                    document.getElementById("quantity" + count).remove();
                    document.getElementById("amount" + count).remove();
                    document.getElementById("discount" + count).remove();
                    count = count - 1;
                                          }

            </script>

            </head>

            <body>
              <form action="invoicesubmit.php" method="POST">

<?php 
echo "<table border='2'>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<th>Description</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n"; 
echo "</tr>"; echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>"?>


<input type='text' size="50" name='name[]' value='Examination and Consultation' readonly/>
<?php "</td>"; echo "<td>"?>
<input type='text' size="50" name='quantity[]' value='' />
<?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?>
<input type='text' size="50" name='amount[]' value='' />
<?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?>
<input type='text' size="50" name='discount[]' value='' />
<?php "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>"?>


<div id="name"></div>

<?php "</td>"; echo "<td>"?>

<div id="quantity"></div>

<?php "</td>"; echo "<td>"?>

<div id="amount"></div>

<?php "</td>"; echo "<td>"?>

<div id="discount"></div>

<?php "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; ?> <br /> 

<input type="button" value="Add Description" onClick="addTextArea();">

 &nbsp; 

Customer Name: <input type="text" value="" name="cust_name" />

 <input type="button" value="Remove Description" onClick="removeTextArea();"> &nbsp; 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
              </form>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Page Two (Store into database)

```
<?php require_once ("includes/session.php");?> 
<?php require_once ("includes/db_connection.php");?> 
<?php require_once ("includes/functions.php");?>
<?php require_once ("includes/validation_function.php");?> 

<?php
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Description</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Total_amt</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    { // Process the form
     $name_array = $_POST['name'];
     $quantity_array = $_POST['quantity'];
    $amount_array = $_POST['amount'];
     $discount_array = $_POST['discount'];
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++)
          {
           $name = $name_array[$i];
           $quantity = $quantity_array[$i];
          $amount = $amount_array[$i];
          $discount = $discount_array[$i];
           $total_amt = ($amount - ($amount * ($discount / 100))) * $quantity;
           $cust_name = mysqlprep($_POST["cust_name"]);

            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO invoicesub (";
            $query.= " cust_name, description, quantity, amount, discount, total";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cust_name}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $quantity . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $amount . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $discount . "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $total_amt . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

           if ($result)
                      {
                       redirect_to("invoicesubmitfinal.php");
                      }
                 }
?>
```

page three (Print and store into 2nd database)

```
 <?php
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query.= "FROM invoicesub";
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(amount) FROM invoicesub") or die(mysqli_error());

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(quantity) FROM invoicesub") or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {
        $result2 = mysqli_query("SELECT sum(total) FROM invoicesub") or die(mysqli_error());
        while ($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
            {
            echo $rows['amount'];
            echo $rows1['quantity'];
            echo $rows2['total'];
            $finaltotal = $rows2['total'];
            }
        }
    } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Always give proper code indentation so that other people can read it.

Comment: you have forgot some echo statements like in this line `<?php "</td>"; echo "<td>"?>`  put it correct like `<?php echo "</td>"; echo "<td>";?>`

Comment: I had to use 3 different code editors to format your HTML, PHP and JavaScript separately -_-"

Comment: Sorry about the identations, my page went haywire on me and wouldnt indent properly. I sort of fixed it now. Hope it is easier to see now.

Answer (score 0):

Since, your requirement is not really understandable, i tried clearing some errors & changed the SQL. if you, refrain your questions, along with the included function & connection files, we can only take a look. The modified codes are shown below.

invoicesubmit.php

```
<?php require_once ("includes/session.php");?> 
<?php require_once ("includes/db_connection.php");?> 
<?php require_once ("includes/functions.php");?>
<?php require_once ("includes/validation_function.php");?> 

<?php
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Description</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Total_amt</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Process the form
    $name_array = $_POST['name'];
    $quantity_array = $_POST['quantity'];
    print_r($quantity_array);
    $amount_array = $_POST['amount'];
    $discount_array = $_POST['discount'];
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($name_array); $i++){
        $name = $name_array[$i];
        $quantity = $quantity_array[$i];
        $amount = $amount_array[$i];
        $discount = $discount_array[$i];
        $total_amt = ($amount - ($amount * ($discount / 100))) * $quantity;
        $cust_name = mysqlprep( $_POST["cust_name"]);

            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO invoicesub (";
            $query.= " cust_name, description, quantity, amount, discount, total";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cust_name}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total_amt}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $quantity . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $amount . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $discount . "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $total_amt . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

          if ($result){
            redirect_to("invoicesubmitfinal.php?cname=$cust_name");
           }
}
?>
```

invoicesubmitfinal.php

```
<?php
require_once ("includes/db_connection.php");
global $connection;
$name=$_REQUEST['cname'];
$sql1="SELECT sum(amount) as amount, sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(total) as total FROM invoicesub where cust_name=$name";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error());

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $rows['amount'];
    echo $rows['quantity'];
    echo $rows['total'];
}
?>
```

Comment: erm, my question is i want to make a small billing system. 
The first page is a form which allows the user to type in what services they want along with the quantity or cost of it. They are also able to key in the discount amount. 

These variables are sent to the 2nd page which will calculate the total cost of each services. And then all the variables will be parsed into a database. 

The 3rd page is supposed to call out the variables from the said database.I just want sum the "total" variable in the 2nd page and then print it out on the 3rd page

Comment: I think, thats what i have written ... what errors are you facing with my answer ?

Comment: erm i want to insert the printed amount, quantity and total into another database. The thing is, if i have customer name that is inserted into the database in page2, How do i call that customer name also in page3 so that i can re-insert it again into a separate table?

Comment: is it to another database or another table ?

Comment: erm another table in the same database.

Comment: Using invoicesubmit.php the cust_name, description, quantity, amount, discount, total values will be inserted into table invoicesub and sum of amount, quantity, and total using the values from table invoicesub  will be displayed in invoicesubmitfinal.php. May i exactly know what are you looking for ?

Comment: erm sorry for not being clear, im new to this. 
I want to not only show the values from the table invoicesub in invoicesubmitfinal but also store the values as well.I also want to make the new sum of the total column as a variable and store that variable into another table called invoicefinal as well together with the variables shown in invoicesubmitfinal.php

Comment: I got an error, Undefined variable: result on line 48 for invoicesubmit but I dont see anything wrong with the query line or that it has not been set. Can anybody tell me the problem?